# PowerShell: AzureRM - Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login error

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to capture an image of an Azure VM I have created through my Azure account, as described in the Microsoft documentation: [How to capture a VM image from a generalized Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image).

I have successfully [Generalized the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-generalize-vhd?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json) and then performed the login and subscription selection running the following commands in PowerShell (PSVersion 5.1.14393.953) with Admin rights:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "my_subscription_id"
```

Next step is to stop (deallocate) the VM and set it to generalized, which can be done with following commands, still according to the documentation:

```
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName my-resource-group -Name my-vm-name
Set-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName my-resource-group -Name my-vm-name -Generalized
```

However, both commands fail from PowerShell with a similar error. As I was able to stop (deallocate) the VM from [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com), I am now trying to succeed on the Set-AzureRmVM call. Below is the error I am receiving from PowerShell:

> Set-AzureRmVM : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName configit-build -Name build-server -G ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-AzureRmVM], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.SetAzureVMCommand

Any help is more than appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you check your Azure PowerShell version by using the cmdlet `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Comment: Could you check the result `Get-AzureRmSubscription`? Do you have multiple subscriptions?

Comment: I only have one subscription and upgrading to 3.7.0 actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you could check as the following ways:

1.Check the result `Get-AzureRmSubscription`.

If you have multiple subscriptions, please ensure you have the correct subscription. You could the subscription ID from Azure Portal.

[image]

2.Check Azure PowerShell version. You could use the following cmdlet.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

The latest version is 3.7.0. If you don't have the latest version, you could download the msi file and install it.  You could download from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.7.0-March2017).

Comment: Hi, updating to 3.7.0 (from 3.5.0) as you pointed actually solved the issue and I was able to complete the image creation! Thank you very much!